# Spring Security Active directory LDAP Authentication error

Tags: spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap, spring-security-ldap

When i am using Spring Security Active directory LDAP Authentication , i am getting  an error saying **PartialResultException** when user was authenticated.  Also i have created a test runner file where it authenticates the user without an error but when am authenticating against the active directory i am unable to authenticate. Appreciate your valuable help.

**Test Runner2.java File**

```
package com.company.test;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;


public class Runner2 {

    private static String providerUrl = "ldap://ADHO.COMPANY.NET:389";

    private static String principle = "@company.ad";

    public static final String SEARCH_BY_SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME = "(sAMAccountName=%s)";

    public static boolean authenticateAD(String user , String password) throws Exception {

        InitialDirContext context=null;
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        String securityPrinciple = user + principle;
        System.out.println("Security principal to search ->"+securityPrinciple);

        // Configure our directory context environment.
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, securityPrinciple);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        try {

        context = new InitialDirContext(env);       
        return true;

        }catch(AuthenticationException e) {

         throw new AuthenticationException();

        }catch(Exception e) {

            throw new Exception();
        }
        finally { 
            try {
                if (context != null) {
                    context.close();
                }
            } catch (NamingException e) {

            } 
        } 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String r1 = "USRXXXX;
        String r2 = "Pass#word102";
        authenticateAD(r1,r2);
    }

}
```

**ldap.properties file**

```
ad.domain=company.ad
ad.url=ldap://ADHO.COMPANY.NET:389/
```

**SpringSecurityConfig.java file**

```
package com.company.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;

import com.onezero.config.AuthenticationEntryPoint;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:ldap.properties")
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntry() throws Exception {
      return new AuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/welcome","/atm/**","/atm2/**","/**","/survey/**","/usrauth/**").authenticated()
           .and()
           .httpBasic()
           .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntry())
           .and()
           .exceptionHandling()
           .and()
           .csrf().disable()
           .sessionManagement()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
    env.getProperty("ad.domain"), env.getProperty("ad.url"));

        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);




        return provider;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `PartialResultException` can be thrown when the server returns a referral. That's the server's way of saying "I don't know what you're talking about, but I know who does." There is a good explanation of options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412236/how-to-resolve-javax-naming-partialresultexception). One is to set:

```
env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
```

That will tell it to send the request to wherever the server told us to go. But I don't think that's a good solution. You will end up making two network requests when only one will do. Changing your configuration to point to the right place is a better option.

One way to figure out what it's complaining about is to inspect the [`resolvedName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/NamingException.html#resolvedName) property of the `PartialResultException` object. That should tell you where it is sending you, and you can change your configuration to point there in the first place.

I'm not a Java developer, so these are a lot of guesses, but I do know how AD works. Give it a try anyway.